Condensing a verbose select statement in KDB
In KDB, for each ticker I'd like to get all the rows where signal=1 except the first occurrence in each ticker.
og:([]
    ticker:raze 5#/:(`AAPL`GOOGL`MSFT);
    date:raze 3#enlist 2023.01.01+til 5;
    price:45 46 47 48 49,100 102 101 103 105,200 201 199 202 205;
    volume:1000 1100 900 1200 1300,500 520 510 530 550,300 310 290 320 330;
    signal:0 0 1 1 0,0 1 1 1 0,0 0 0 1 1 / Example entry signals
 );

t:select from og where signal=1;
t:update valid:1b from t where date>(min;date) fby ticker;
t:select from t where valid;
show t: delete valid from t; / correct but verbose

q)og
ticker date       price volume signal
-------------------------------------
AAPL   2023.01.01 45    1000   0     
AAPL   2023.01.02 46    1100   0     
AAPL   2023.01.03 47    900    1     
AAPL   2023.01.04 48    1200   1     
AAPL   2023.01.05 49    1300   0     
GOOGL  2023.01.01 100   500    0     
GOOGL  2023.01.02 102   520    1     
GOOGL  2023.01.03 101   510    1     
GOOGL  2023.01.04 103   530    1     
GOOGL  2023.01.05 105   550    0     
MSFT   2023.01.01 200   300    0     
MSFT   2023.01.02 201   310    0     
MSFT   2023.01.03 199   290    0     
MSFT   2023.01.04 202   320    1     
MSFT   2023.01.05 205   330    1 

q)t
ticker date       price volume signal 
-------------------------------------
AAPL   2023.01.04 48    1200   1         
GOOGL  2023.01.03 101   510    1          
GOOGL  2023.01.04 103   530    1          
MSFT   2023.01.05 205   330    1        

I find my approach quite verbose, and I'm wondering if one can be terser and hopefully more efficient. Just for reference, the naive/incorrect select statement below gives an undesired result
q) select by ticker from og where date>date[first where signal=1] / incorrect
ticker| date       price volume signal
------| ------------------------------
AAPL  | 2023.01.05 49    1300   0     
GOOGL | 2023.01.05 105   550    0     
MSFT  | 2023.01.05 205   330    1


You can achieve this succinctly using fby (https://code.kx.com/q/ref/fby), and the virtual index column i:
q)select from og where signal=1,i>(first;i)fby ticker
ticker date       price volume signal
-------------------------------------
AAPL   2023.01.04 48    1200   1
GOOGL  2023.01.03 101   510    1
GOOGL  2023.01.04 103   530    1
MSFT   2023.01.05 205   330    1


Interestingly, in trying to see if the order of the where clauses makes a difference I found that: select from og where i>(first;i),signal=1 fby ticker fails with a 'length error.  Any idea why? It also appears that first i refers to the first member where signal=1. Where's this behaviour documented?

Yes, your syntax is wrong for both clauses. Look at the link I provided for fby to see how you should apply it. The result of any where clause should return a list of booleans which is used to filter the table. Re your second question, the filtering is applied to the table in succession, i.e. the fby clause is only applied to records of the table that have signal=1
